# vb.net HttpWebRequest with JSON data fails but works when encoded in URL

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, httprequest, suitecrm

I am trying to create an httpwebrequest in vb.net to POST to suitecrm but I get an invalid login every time.  The problem seems to be with the JSON content itself because it works just fine if I make it part of the url.

First I am creating a newtonsoft JObject:

```
Dim jobjReq = New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty(
    "user_auth",
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("user_name", username),
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("password", Security.HashStringMD5(password))
    ))
)
Dim jobjReq2 = New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("rest_data", jobjReq))
```

This is the resulting JSON that is created

```
{
  "rest_data": {
    "user_auth": {
      "user_name": "XXXXXX",
      "password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

And passed to this function:

```
Public Sub New(urlString As String, method As String, jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
    Dim uri As New Uri(urlString)
    httpRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Try
        With httpRequest
            .Method = method
            .KeepAlive = True
            .UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3"
            .ContentType = "application/json"
            Dim stringReq = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject)
            Dim byteData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringReq)
            .ContentLength = byteData.Length
            Dim postreqstream As System.IO.Stream = .GetRequestStream()
            postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
            postreqstream.Close()
        End With
    Catch exception As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox(exception.Status.ToString & vbLf & exception.Message.ToString & vbLf)
    End Try
```

It comes back with an invalid login every time no matter what I try.

However, if I serialize the JObject and concatenate it to the URL like this:
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/SuiteCRM/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"XXXXX","password":"XXXXXXXXXXXX"}}
It works just fine.

I have been fine doing it the second way and can post and get records just fine, except that now I need to post a large record and I am hitting a limit on the length of the URL

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldnt be serializing the `rest_data`... You dont need `jobjReq2`... what does `stringReq` look like when you set a breakpoint?

Comment: {
  "user_auth": {
    "user_name": "admin",
    "password": "03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034"
  }
}

That doesn't work either.  I also tried creating the URL as
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/SuiteCRM/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=
then sending just the above as JSON data and that doesn't work either